# How to disable SmartyStreets/LiveAddress via onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, smartystreets

I've inherited SmartyStreets/LiveAddress code implemented in a SquirrelCart shopping cart application, and need help figuring out the syntax to disable the SmartyStreets/LiveAddress verification with an onclick event that copies the billing address fields into the shipping address fields.

Especially for international addresses (i.e., outside the U.S.) it's really annoying to have to go through the verification process for the shipping address after they've already verified the billing address.

I currently have the addresses initialized like so:

```
/* SmartyStreets */
jQuery.LiveAddress(
    {
        key: "18924899",
        invalidMessage: "Not a valid US Postal address.</br>Please correct or certify below.",
        debug: "true",
        addresses: [
            // Squirrelcart billing address
            {
                id:         'Billing',
                street:     '#Bill_Street',
                city:       '#Bill_City',
                state:      '#Bill_State_or_Province',
                zipcode:    '#Bill_Postal_Code',
                country:    '#Bill_Country'
            },
            // Squirrelcart shipping address
            {
                id:         'Shipping',
                street:     '#Ship_Street',
                city:       '#Ship_City',
                state:      '#Ship_State_or_Province',
                zipcode:    '#Ship_Postal_Code',
                country:    '#Ship_Country'
            },
            // Squirrelcart account address
            {
                id:         'Account',
                street:     '#Street',
                city:       '#City',
                state:      '#State_or_Province',
                zipcode:    '#Postal_Code',
                country:    '#Country'
            }
        ],
        autoVerify: false,
        deactivate: 'Shipping'
    }
);
```

The HTML code associated with copying the billing address into the shipping address is:

```
<p>If your shipping address is the same as your billing address, clicking the 
   "Same as Billing button will copy it into the fields below for you. 
   If your shipping address is different, please type it in the fields below.</p>

<div align="center"><a class="btn btn_same_as_billing" href="#">Same as Billing</a></div>
```

Relevant SquirrelCart JavaScript functions:

```
/*************************************************************
    Setup various aspects of the store
*************************************************************/
function scStoreSetup() {

    < ... snip ... >

    $$('.btn_same_as_billing').addEvent('click',function(evt) {scAddressCopy(evt);});

    < ... snip ... >

}

/*************************************************************
    Function copies fields from billing to shipping address
*************************************************************/
function scAddressCopy(evt) {
    // prevents the page from jumping position
    evt.stop();

    var form    = document.address_form;
    var billFldId, shipFldId, billFld, shipFld;

    // loop thru fields
    for(x=0; x < form.elements.length; x++) {
        billFldId   = form.elements[x].id;
        billFld     = form.elements[x];

        // if we are on a bill field
        if (billFldId.indexOf('Bill_') != -1) {
            // change id to matching ship field
            shipFldId = billFldId.replace('Bill_','Ship_');

            // grab ship field and set it
            shipFld = document.getElementById(shipFldId);
            if (shipFld) shipFld.value = billFld.value;
        }
    }
}

/*************************************************************
    Handle things specific to address form
*************************************************************/
function addrForm(elem, evt) {
    if (elem.id == 'Bill_State_Other' && evt.type == 'keyup') {
        if (elem.value.length) {
            // set state or province field to 'Other'
            if (document.getElementById('Bill_State_or_Province')) document.getElementById('Bill_State_or_Province').value = 2
        }
    } else if (elem.id == 'Ship_State_Other' && evt.type == 'keyup') {
        if (elem.value.length) {
            // set state or province field to 'Other'
            if (document.getElementById('Ship_State_or_Province')) document.getElementById('Ship_State_or_Province').value = 2
        }
    } else if (elem.id == 'Bill_State_or_Province' && evt.type == 'change') {
        if (document.getElementById('Bill_State_Other')) {
            var stateOther = document.getElementById('Bill_State_Other');
            if (elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value == '2') {
                stateOther.value = '';
                stateOther.focus();
            } else {
                stateOther.value='';
            }
        }
    } else if (elem.id == 'Ship_State_or_Province' && evt.type == 'change') {
        if (document.getElementById('Ship_State_Other')) {
            var stateOther = document.getElementById('Ship_State_Other');
            if (elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value == '2') {
                stateOther.value = '';
                stateOther.focus();
            } else {
                stateOther.value='';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like I should be able to disable or deactivate LiveAddress (especially for international addresses) by using an onclick event such as, for instance,

```
<a class="btn btn_same_as_billing" href="#" onclick="$('form#address_form').deactivate('Shipping');">Same as Billing</a>
```

where "address_form" is the form's id:

```
<form id="address_form" class="sc_form" accept-charset="utf-8" name="address_form" action="<?php print $Form_Action?>" method="post">
```

I'm having real difficulty getting the syntax dialed in. Help me here?

Best,
Mattie

Comment: International addresses don't go through verification if the selected country does not look like a US value. Also, the deactivate function is on the liveaddress object, not a form. See https://smartystreets.com/docs/plugin/functions#deactivate

Comment: In the onchange event for the billing country in our drop-down select list, LiveAddress does indeed deactivate -- for the billing address only. However, in the onclick event afterwards to copy the billing address to the shipping address fields, LiveAddress isn't deactivated even though the billing address -- including the country -- fields are successfully copied into the shipping address fields. It seems as though LiveAddress doesn't understand that the shipping address changed.

Comment: And I *did* look through the SmartyStreets documentation before posting here. In fact, I printed out that "Plugin functions" page yesterday, and tried more syntax variations than I care to admit trying to get this working. (BTW, I'd really love to see specific examples of usage for the plugins in the documentation that could be used and/or modified for situations like this.)

Anyway, I think the deactivate plugin function will work for us, but, again, I'm having trouble with the syntax. Try again, please? I'll look forward to hearing from you!

Best,
Mattie

Comment: You're right. If the fields are changing by a script, it's unlikely that the change event is firing, since the browsers only fire it when the user leaves the field. It's probably necessary to invoke the change event on a field after changing its value programmatically.

Comment: So, do you think I can deactivate SmartyStreets verification with an onclick event, and, if so, what syntax should be used?

Comment: Something like this, maybe? onclick="$('form#address_form').deactivate('Shipping');"

Comment: Or could we add some code to the JavaScript code that copies the billing fields to the shipping fields to fire off something to the SmartyStreets/LiveAddress code?

Comment: What do you think, Matt?

Comment: Deactivate is not a method on the #address-form; you have to call it from the liveaddress object. That's why it's not working.

Comment: Is the integration syntax at the very top of my first post incorrect? (Notice I've got "deactivate: 'Shipping'" in there.) Thanks! I look forward to hearing from you with anticipation.

Comment: Something like `var liveaddress = jQuery.LiveAddress(...)` and then you can do `liveaddress.deactivate('addressID')`-- sorry for the confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="button" name="Copy" value="Copy Billing Address" id="billingtoshipping_checkbox"> 

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#billingtoshipping_checkbox").click(function(){
            $("[id^='shipping_']").each(function(){
                data=$(this).attr("id")
                tmpID = data.split('shipping_');
                $(this).val($("#billing_"+tmpID[1]).val())
            })
        });
    });

</script>
```